# Interrupt and, if necessary, terminate a program at regular intervals in c++

Tags: c++, signals, kill, alarm, pause

I need your help. Program A executes program B with fork(). Every 5 seconds the process belonging to program B is interrupted. If the user enters any key within a certain time, the process is continued and interrupted again after the same time interval. If no key is entered, both program A and program B are terminated prematurely. I have tried the following code, but it does not work. Any suggestions/tips that will help me?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;

int pid;

void signal_handler(int signum) {
    cout << "Programm B is interrupted. Please enter any key within 5 or the programm will be terminated" << endl;
    kill(pid,SIGSTOP);
    alarm(5);
    pause();
    alarm(5);

}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  //Usage
  if(string(argv[1]) == "h" || string(argv[1]) == "help"){
    cout << "usage" << endl;
    return 0;
  }

  signal(SIGALRM, signal_handler);
  pid = fork();

  if (pid == 0) {

    cout << "Name of programm B: " << argv[1] << endl;
    cout << "PID of programm B: " << getpid() << endl;
    execvp(argv[1], &argv[1]);

  } else if (pid > 0) {

    cout << "PID of programm A: " << getpid() << endl;

    high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    waitpid(pid, nullptr, 0);
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();

  
    auto duration = duration_cast<milliseconds>(t2 - t1).count();
    cout << "Computing time: " << duration << "ms" << endl;
  } else {

    cerr << "error << endl;
    return 1;

}
  return 0;
}
```

Any help or sulution. I am a beginner in c++ btw.

Comment: Side note: [The list of things you can safely do in a signal handler](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) is pretty short and not every thing you're doing in that handler is on the list. Typically you set a flag and get back out of the handler to let another task loop check the flag and handle it.

Comment: If `B` is SIGSTOPped at 00:00:05, and then the user presses a key 00:00:08, is the next STOP signal sent at 00:00:10 or at 00:00:13?

Comment: Signals aren't a beginner topic, I would say, but you don't need advanced (or any) C++ to code with them. Your example doesn't really benefit from any of the ++ stuff and could just as well be written in plain C.

Answer (score 2):

Signals can get tricky and there are lots of issues with your approach.

You should:

- kick off the timer (`alarm(5)`) in `main`
- do the sighandler registration and timer kick-off after you've spawned the child (or you somewhat risk running the signal handler in the child in between `fork` and `execvp`)
- use `sigaction` rather than `signal` to register the signal, as the former has clear portable semantics unlike the latter
- loop on `EINTR` around `waitpid` (as signal interruptions will cause `waitpid` to fail with `EINTR`)

As for the handler, it'll need to

- use only [async-signal-safe functions](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html)
- register another `alarm()` around `read`
- unblock `SIGALRM` for the `alarm` around `read` but not before you somehow mark yourself as being in your `SIGALRM` signal handler already so the potential recursive entry of the handler can do a different thing (kill the child and exit)

(For the last point, you could do without signal-unblocking if you register the handler with `.sa_flags = SA_NODEFER`, but that has the downside of opening up your application to stack-overflow caused by many externally sent (via kill) SIGALRMs. If you wanted to handle externally sent `SIGALRM`s precisely, you could register the handler with `.sa_flags=SA_SIGINFO` and use `info->si_code` to differentiate between user-sends and alarm-sends of `SIGALRM`, presumably aborting on externally-sent ones)

It could look something like this (based on your code):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>

//AS-safe raw io helper functions
ssize_t             /* Write "n" bytes to a descriptor  */
writen(int fd, const char *ptr, size_t n)
{
    size_t      nleft;
    ssize_t     nwritten;

    nleft = n;
    while (nleft > 0) {
        if ((nwritten = write(fd, ptr, nleft)) < 0) {
            if (nleft == n)
                return(-1); /* error, return -1 */
            else
                break;      /* error, return amount written so far */
        } else if (nwritten == 0) {
            break;
        }
        nleft -= nwritten;
        ptr   += nwritten;
    }
    return(n - nleft);      /* return >= 0 */
}
ssize_t writes(int fd, char const *str0) { return writen(fd,str0,strlen(str0)); }
ssize_t writes2(char const *str0) { return writes(2,str0); }

//AS-safe sigprockmask helpers (they're in libc too, but not specified as AS-safe)
int sigrelse(int sig){
    sigset_t set; sigemptyset(&set); sigaddset(&set,sig);
    return sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK,&set,0);
}
int sighold(int sig){
    sigset_t set; sigemptyset(&set); sigaddset(&set,sig);
    return sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK,&set,0);
}

#define INTERRUPT_TIME 5

using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;

int pid;
volatile sig_atomic_t recursing_handler_eh; //to differentiate recursive executions of signal_handler


void signal_handler(int signum) {
    char ch;
    if(!recursing_handler_eh){
        kill(pid,SIGSTOP);

        writes2("Programm B is interrupted. Please type enter within 5 seconds or the programm will be terminated\n");

        alarm(5);
        recursing_handler_eh = 1;
        sigrelse(SIGALRM);

        if (1!=read(0,&ch,1)) signal_handler(signum);
        alarm(0);
        sighold(SIGALRM);

        writes2("Continuing");
        kill(pid,SIGCONT);
        recursing_handler_eh=0;
        alarm(INTERRUPT_TIME);
        return;
    }
    kill(pid,SIGTERM);
    _exit(1);

}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  //Usage
  if(string(argv[1]) == "h" || string(argv[1]) == "help"){
    cout << "usage" << endl;
    return 0;
  }

  pid = fork();

  if (pid == 0) {
    cout << "Name of programm B: " << argv[1] << endl;
    cout << "PID of programm B: " << getpid() << endl;
    execvp(argv[1], &argv[1]);

  } else if (pid < 0) { cerr << "error" <<endl; return 1; }

  struct sigaction sa; sa.sa_handler = signal_handler; sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask); sa.sa_flags=0; sigaction(SIGALRM, &sa,0);
  //signal(SIGALRM, signal_handler);
  alarm(INTERRUPT_TIME);

  cout << "PID of programm A: " << getpid() << endl;

  high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
  int r;
  do r = waitpid(pid, nullptr, 0); while(r==-1 && errno==EINTR);
  high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();


  auto duration = duration_cast<milliseconds>(t2 - t1).count();
  cout << "Computing time: " << duration << "ms" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Not that the above will wait only for an enter key. To wait for any key, you'll need to put your terminal in raw/cbreak mode and restore the previous settings on exit (ideally on signal deaths too).